# How to get an option to send a message when i click a button?

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, message, mms

I have created a button. So when I click the button it gives me an option to send message and the view of the contact list.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside the onClick() of your button,launch the sms activity :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));

startActivity(sendIntent);
```

You can add extras to populate your own message and such like this

```
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", x);
```

One more way is :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(intent);
```

If b is your button then :

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
        sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));

        startActivity(sendIntent);  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("sms:"));
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "abcdefghi"); 
startActivity(sendIntent);



Try iy...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to send message

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, SMS.class), 0);
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);

where SMS.class is your current activity and in the manifeast file add the below permissions...

Answer (score 0):

startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNumber)));

The above code is working fine.....